# "Strong" qualify in objc

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

I create a new project using xcode4.2, and view the AppDelegate:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

I know the `strong`  is a new qualify in Xcode for ARC.However I didn't select using ARC while creating the project. As a result it is boring me.
Moreover,what does the below mean:

```
@synthesize window = _window;
```

Is `_window` a instance variable? But it didn't declare in the header file.I can understand if `_window` declared in the header but failed in this style.
Is it kind of modern obj-c runtime?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strong` is effectively the same as `retain`.  I'm not sure if the compiler automatically translates that into retain for non ARC code or not.  If not, it should generate a warning I would think.

```
@synthesize window = _window;
```

says the backing instance variable for the property `window` is `_window`.  In the modern run time for iOS and 64 bit OS X, the instance variable is created automatically if you don't explicitly declare it in your header.

Comment: @scorpiozj I don't know.  If it compiles, the answer is probably yes.